# Get parent uid data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm trying to get UID data.

Here are my Firebase database structure

[image]

and the rules

[image]

my code in .ts

```
firebase.database().ref('/appointment/').orderByChild('keys').equalTo(this.user.$key).once('value').then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key);
  });
})
```

but i got this in console

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "keys" at /appointment to your security rules for better performance
```

Please, any idea on what I am doing wrong?? how can i get the uid??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a child called `key` in the database, this is what you have:

```
appointment
        userid
            randomKey
                 almt:...
                 gr:...
```

If you want to retrieve the current userid, then do this:

```
 var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
 var uid=user.uid;
```

If you just want to retrieve it from the database, then do this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/appointment/').once('value').then(snapshot => {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
  console.log(child.key);
 });
})
```

This will loop inside the direct child of `appointment` and `child.key` will retrieve the `uid`

Comment: thanks Peter, but i want to retrieve all userid as admin, not the current userid. How can i do that??

Comment: try the second option, I gave in the answer

Comment: Thanks Peter, it works.. Will you help me once again ?? how do i show the userid along with the data if i do `snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
       child.forEach(function(grandchild) {
        console.log(grandchild.key);
        console.log(grandchild.val());
       });
      console.log(child.key);
      });
     })` in the front view??